# How to select a value from a list with jq

Tags: jq

I have a list of strings of tags related to a docker image.
The array looks like this:

["latest", "SOME_SHA"]

I cannot figure out how to select the value from the list that is not "latest".

I tried to use `jq ´ select(. != "latest"´)` but this returns the entire array, and not just the "SOME_SHA" value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all values not equal to a specific $value, you could use map(select(. != $value)); to select the first such value, if any, you could write:

```
first(.[]|select(. != $value))
```